# How to execute properly InstaPy? InstaPy installation - Nonebit win error

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have installed Python 3,8 on Windows 10, pip, instaPy, I put correct insta_username and insta_password in quickstart.py.

Code, which I used: [InstaPy - follow and unfollow template](https://github.com/InstaPy/instapy-quickstart/blob/master/quickstart_templates/basic_follow-unfollow_activity.py)
I followed instructions in this video: [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwB5mR5PpTg&t=309s)

After running quickstart.py file, error appears:

```py
Error, unable to determine correct filename for Nonebit win
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\qucikstart.py", line 28, in
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 309, in init
self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 110, in set_selenium_local_session
driver_path = geckodriver_path or get_geckodriver()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 36, in get_geckodriver
bin_path, sym_path = gdd.download_and_install()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\webdriverdownloader\webdriverdownloader.py", line 174, in download_and_install
filename_with_path = self.download(version,
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\webdriverdownloader\webdriverdownloader.py", line 129, in download
download_url = self.get_download_url(version, os_name=os_name, bitness=bitness)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\webdriverdownloader\webdriverdownloader.py", line 324, in get_download_url
raise RuntimeError(info_message)
RuntimeError: Error, unable to determine correct filename for Nonebit win
```